# Error al descargar un archivo de mi servidor con codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en **codeigniter 3**, el problema que tengo es al momento de descargar el archivo, al momento de subir el archivo al servidor, guardo en la base de datos la ruta y el nombre generados por la función `do_upload` de **codeigniter**, cuando lo descargo lo descarga bien pero sin contenido, sea para documentos de word excel como pdf, al tratar de abrir estos archivos me los muestra vació y en el caso del pdf no lo abre, al ver los documentos en el servidor están todos completos con su contenido.

Al momento de enviar el archivo lo envio mediante **ajax** utilizando el `FormData` y lo envia de forma correcta.

Aqui el codigo de subir:

```
public function document(){
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'docx|xlsx|pdf';
    $config['upload_path']      = './assets/archivos/doc/';
    $config['remove_spaces']    = TRUE;
    $config['max_size']         = '20048';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $result = array('error' => true, 'mens' => $error, 'estado' => 3);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }else{
        $data = array(
            'nom_doc'  => $this->upload->data('file_name'), 
            'doc_size' => $this->upload->data('file_size'),
            'type_doc' => $this->upload->data('file_type'),
            'ruta_doc' => $this->upload->data('full_path'),
            'id_conf_sist' => 1
        );
        $res = $this->Config_model->insertDocument($data);
        if($res){
            $result = array('error' => false, 'mens' => 'El archivo '.$this->upload->data('raw_name').', a sido guardado correctamente.', 'estado' => 1);
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
    }
}
```

Este seria el código de descargar:

```
public function getDownloadFile($name){
    $data = file_get_contents($this->folder.$name);
    force_download($name,$data);
}
```

Alguien me podría decir cual seria el error por el cual no me descarga bien los archivos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que ocurre es que estas utilizando mal el método `force_download`, ya que en la documentación oficial dice que para descargar un archivo existente en el servidor debes de utilizar el método de la siguiente manera:

```
public function getDownloadFile($name){
    //El primer parámetro es la locación del archivo y el segundo un NULL.
    force_download($this->folder.$name, NULL);
}
```

Te dejo la documentación oficial para mayor información:

> https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html

Comment: Amigo pero en la misma documentación se esta haciendo como lo tengo y de echo me estoy guiando de la documentación, aunque tambien me funciono hacerlo como me dices muchas gracias!!!! amigo me e dado cuenta que al momento de guardar un archivo con un acento por ejemplo tilde, lo guarda asi CapÃ­tulo_11, el nombre seria Capítulo_11, pero lo guarda asi, de-casualidad sabrás como arreglar eso

Comment: Si pero segun la documentación en la manera de lo que estabas haciendo es para generar un nuevo archivo desde 0. Con respecto a tu duda del acento no se mucho al respecto pero puedes abrir una nueva pregunta para ver si te pueden ayudar. Si la pregunta te ayudo a resolver el problema marcala como repuesta valida.